# php how to convert mac path to windows?

Tags: php, windows, macos, cakephp, hyperlink

We are working in such environment where designer team is using MAC whereas we developers are using Windows. We use to share documents hyperlink to each other. Usually it won’t work because of the difference in directory structure of MAC and Windows.

Path in Mac  **//10.0.4.2/009 Project  Folders/02321/Wireframes/layout.psd**

Path in Windows  **\10.0.4.2\009 Project  Folders\02321\Wireframes\layout.psd**

I’m assigned a utility to convert mac links to windows and vice versa in php so that we can share files in better way.

Please give me direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What protocol are you using? Windows does accept slashes ('/') as directory separator, so you could just use / instead of \ in windows, and have the same path everywhere.

Comment: does windows supports ('/') ?

Comment: It does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#MS-DOS.2FMicrosoft_Windows_style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to PHP documentation `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` and `PATH_SEPARATOR` maybe is the best way to do that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

```
<?php
function replace_path($string, $search='/') {
    return str_replace($search, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $string);
}

replace_path('//10.0.4.2/009 Project Folders/02321/Wireframes/layout.psd');

//or 
// replace_path('\10.0.4.2\009 Project Folders\02321\Wireframes\layout.psd', '\');
?>
```

or if you use a PHP server only on Mac Os or only on Windows you must use the following:

```
<?php
function replace_path($string, $search='/') {
    $replace = '/';
    if ($search === '/') {
        $replace = '\\';
    }
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}

echo replace_path('//10.0.4.2/009 Project Folders/02321/Wireframes/layout.psd');

//or
//echo replace_path('\10.0.4.2\009 Project Folders\02321\Wireframes\layout.psd', '\\');
?>
```

Comment: can i change DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant ?

Comment: I've update my answer you've got a function to convert:
Mac Os to Windows
and
Windows to Mac Os

Comment: Code updated for PHP running on Mac Os or Windows server only.